# Preventing calls to my JSON api outside the html app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, api

I've separated my front-end from my back-end, so that they communicate via JSON calls (generated by rails back-end).

i.e, my app calls get_info.json which runs a controller that returns ajax information to the front end.

How do I prevent a random user from directly running the get_info.json script, and thus directly accessing the JSON information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement authentication for the json api.

It can be as simple as passing an api_key param to every request.

Or you can restrict the access to the route to a specific IP.

```
get "/posts" => "posts#show", :constraints => {:ip => '127.0.0.1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If front-end and back-end are in the same RoR application, then you can use CSRF token.

just pass a param to json call like get_info.json?token=<%= form_authenticity_token.html_safe %>, then in your back-end controller check if if params[:token] == form_authenticity_token.

hope this helps you.